# How to create a fail2ban jail and access log for you own application

Tags: security, webserver, iptables, fail2ban

I want my own small nuxt/vue.js application to utilize fail2ban to lock out users with too many incorrect login attempts. I think I have understood how to set up Fail2Ban itself.

**My question is:** what syntax should my access.log follow in order for it to be understood by fail2ban right out of the box? I did not find any answers on that.

### access.log

What is the best practice and what is an approach that will work for fail2ban right out of the box? I am imagining something like this:

```
2019-02-17 15:12:10 login-error from 192.168.1.1 Invalid user 'administrator'
2019-02-17 16:11:10 login-error from 192.168.1.1 Invalid password for user 'admin'
```

### Basic Setup

1) Install Fail2Ban

```sh
sudo apt-get install fail2ban
```

2) Create your own jail

```sh
sudo vim /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

Paste content (and edit to your needs)

```sh
[my-app]

enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = my-app
logpath  = /home/my-user/my-app/logs/access.log
maxretry = 5
```

4) Create your filter

`sudo vim /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/my-app.local`

Paste the content in your my-app.local:

```
[Definition]
failregex = login-error from <HOST>
```

3) Restart the service

```sh
sudo systemctl restart fail2ban.service
```

Now this will monitor the my-app/logs/access.log and lock an IP out after more than 5 incorrect attempts once the log is set up.

Comment: There is answer in your question. You should have separated them in two parts - question, i.e. 'What syntax should... etc' and then post the answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

On log format there should be a very strict separation between IP address and any other user data. The main consideration you need to achieve to prevent an external party from attempting to login with a pattern in which you regex will match an IP address in the user data as opposed to the IP of origin.

Having a log format like yours where an anchor at the start of the line contains no user data (like username), before the IP makes it easy to write a strong regex.

This pattern accounts for most of the [CVE's in fail2ban](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-5567/Fail2ban.html).

To prevent this on your pattern, there is guidance in the [FILTERS](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/0.11/FILTERS) document in the repository.

In the case of the filter provider, a start anchor `^` should be include in the regex (assume the date/time has been removed).

You should also block an invalid user the same way as an invalid password. Without this a user could enumerate what valid users exist by attempting the same login 5 times.